# Generating random vector that's linearly independent of a set of vectors

Tags: c, linear-algebra, vector-graphics

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that will allow me to generate a random N-dimensional real-valued vector that's linearly independent with respect to a set of already-generated vectors.  I *don't* want to force them to be orthogonal, only linearly independent.  I know Graham-Schmidt exists for the orthogonalization problem, but is there a weaker form that only gives you linearly independent vectors?

Comment: Just try generating N random numbers.  Theoretically, the probability of generating a vector that is linearly independent with the previous M vectors (for M < N) is 0.  On a computer this probability isn't 0 (because floating point is discrete), but the probability is still vanishingly small.

Comment: How big is N? How important is speed? How does randomness play a role? Do you care if the newly generated 'random' vector almost overlaps with the previous? And out of curiosity, what is the application? I am really curious to know what kind of application does not prefer a new orthogonal vector instead of a simply linearly independent one.

Comment: @flebool N isn't that big, probably on the order of 20 or so.  Speed's nice but not critical.  The randomness is just because I'm trying to stochastically sample a big space.  We'd have to define what "almost" overlaps means, since I want linear independence, they have to not overlap by at least some amount.   I'm trying to solve an ICA-like problem but my mixing matrix almost certainly won't be unitary.

Comment: @Kyle can you explain how the probability is zero?  If I generate (1,2,3) and then (2,4,6) for N=3, those aren't linearly independent and it's merely unlikely, but not impossible to occur...

Comment: @gct If you're sampling from a continuous probability distribution (i.e. picking random real numbers), then the probability of getting two linearly dependent vectors is 0.  It's like asking what the probability of picking the exact same number twice in a row would be.  For a continuous random variable, that probability is 0.  A computer deals with discrete values, but as long as there's enough of those discrete values, the probability is going to be very small.

Comment: @Kyle that's a very good point, I had't thought about the fact that vectors could be arbitrarily close and still linearly independent, I'll have to ponder on what exactly "independent enough" would mean in my case...

Comment: For a mere 20 numbers, you can do an exhaustive search, there's only 2^N possible combinations. Of course, since there's 52 bits to a double, a good randomizer should only have a 1/2^32 chance of hitting one of those combinations anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1.  Generate random vector `vr`.

Step 2.  Copy `vr` to `vo` and update as follows: for every already generated vector `v` in `v1, v2... vn`, subtract the projection of `vo` on `vi`.

The result is a random vector orthogonal to the subspace spanned by `v1, v2... vn`.  If that subspace is a basis, then it is the zero vector, of course :)

The decision of whether the initial vector was linearly independent can be made based on the comparison of the norm of vr to the norm of vo.  Non-linearly independent vectors will have a vo-norm which is zero or nearly zero (some numerical precision issues may make it a small nonzero number on the order of a few times epsilon, this can be tuned in an application-dependent way).

Pseudocode:

```
vr = random_vector()
vo = vr
for v in (v1, v2, ... vn):
    vo = vo - dot( vr, v ) / norm( v )
if norm(vo) < k1 * norm(vr):
    # this vector was mostly contained in the spanned subspace
else:
    # linearly independent, go ahead and use
```

Here k1 is a very small number, 1e-8 to 1e-10 perhaps?

You can also go by the *angle* between vr and the subspace: in that case, calculate it as `theta = arcsin(norm(vo) / norm(vr))`.  Angles substantially different from zero correspond to linearly independent vectors.

Comment: ..this is gram-schmidt,as the OP said.

Comment: Yeah that's Graham-Schmidt, which is actually detrimental in this case.  I'm trying to do an ICA-like algorithm, but the catch is my mixing matrix is almost always going to be non-unitary...

Comment: @gct: Oh, I think I see.  Why not: run a vector through this, and if the result is nonzero, then the original is linearly independent?  In practice, you want to compare the norm of the result to the norm of the original.  See update above.

Comment: @Alex I thought about it but I don't think that's sufficient.  You'd have to compare the vector against each previous vector, as well as each possible sum of two previous vectors, three previous vectors, ... up to N-1 previous.  It'd get combinatoric pretty quick.

Comment: @gct: If the vector does not lie in the subspace, then it is linearly independent of any set of vectors chosen from the subspace.  I think there is no combinatorial component, you just have to see if it is "out of plane".

Comment: @Kyle I'll have to think on that, you may be right, my head's all pfleh right now though =D

Comment: @gct gram schmidt gives you an orthogonal n-dimensional basis if and only if the n starting vectors were linearly independent to begin with. This is because the vectors are guaranteed to span the same space as the original vectors..

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat OTT scheme is to generate a NxN non-singular matrix, and use it's columns (or rows) as the N linearly independent vectors.

To generate a non=singular matrix one could generate it's SVD and multiply up. In more detail:

a/ generate a 'random' NxN orthogonal matrix U

b/ generate a 'random' NxN diagonal matrix S with positive numbers in the diagonal

c/ generate a 'random' NxN orthogonal matrix V

d/ compute

```
M = U*S*V'
```

To generate a 'random' orthogonal matrix U, one can use the fact that every orthogonal matrix can be written as a product of Household relectors, that is of matrices of the form

```
H(v) = I - 2*v*v'/(v'*v)
```

where v is a non zero random vector.
So one could

```
initialise U to I
for( i=1..N)
   generate a none zero vector v
   update: U := H(v)*U
```

Note that if all these matrix multiplications become burdonesome, one could write a special routine to do the update of U. Applying H(v) to a vector u is O(N):

```
u -> u - 2*(h'*u)/(h'*h) * h
```

and so applying H to U can be done in O(N squared) rather than O( N cubed)

One advantage of this scheme is that one has some control over 'how linearly independent' the vectors are. The product of the diagonal elements is (up to sign) the determinant of M, so that if this product is 'very small' the vectors are 'almost' linearly dependent