# Creating random linearly independent vectors

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-algebra

I can generate a random vector with

```
a = torch.rand(10)
>>> tensor([0.6432, 0.7512, 0.8835, 0.4268, 0.7681, 0.4709, 0.2722, 0.0510, 0.8463,
        0.9003])
```

However, how can I generate N more vectors (e.g. N=5: `b,c,d,e,f`) that will be linearly independent of the other vectors (i.e `a` is independent of any of `b,c,d,e,f`, `b` is independent of any of `a,c,d,e,f`, etc.)?

Comment: Since you are working in 10-dimensional space, you can have at most 10 linearly independent vectors. Pretty much any 10 random vectors should work - given 9 random vectors whose span is a 9-dimensional hyperplane in 10-d space, it's extremely unlikely that the 10th vector would fall perfectly inside that hyperplane.

Comment: Makes sense! I just must guarantee that they will be linearly independent (which is why I didn't just generated 10 random ones)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways to achieve this. However, there are some restrictions to each of them.
For an *n-dimensional* space, the first way is to create *n* random vectors and check for linear independence using determinants. Check out [here](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/lindep/lindep.html) for more information about the process.

The second way is to generate vectors one by one. Create a random vector, then using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210354/generating-random-vector-thats-linearly-independent-of-a-set-of-vectors), create a new independent vector, then create the third one, and so on.

Comment: Perfect, thank! I used the first method with the determinant as Pytorch has an easy function to calculate it ( so I just need to check that it's not 0)