# Generating orthonormal vectors to a given set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to simulate a problem in physics for which I require a Unitary operator in a Hilbert space with an inner product defined as transpose(x*)x. Given two orthogonal column vectors, I want to generate more orthonormal vectors. Here is the way I tried approaching this problem. I randomly generate complex vectors and subtract their projections onto other already available orthogonal vectors [Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210354/generating-random-vector-thats-linearly-independent-of-a-set-of-vectors). And then I check the norm with respect to the inner product (InProd). Here is an attempt to implement this using python.

```
def stinemod():
    comped = [[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0]]
    
    d = len(comped[0])
    r = len(comped) 
    while(r<d):
        randr = np.random.rand(d)
        randc = np.random.rand(d)
        vr  = randr + 1j*randc
        vo = vr
        for v in comped:
            vo = vo - (InProd(vr,v)*np.array(v)/InProd(v,v))
            k = 1e-10
        if(InProd(vo,vo)<k*InProd(vr,vr)):
            pass
        else:
            r = r+1
            comped.append(np.array(vr)/InProd(vr,vr))
    return(np.transpose(comped))
```

But on running this code and checking unitarity using,

```
A = stinemod()
print(abs(np.matmul(np.transpose(np.conj(A)),A)))
```

Output:

```
[[1.         0.         0.28003392 0.24068132 0.1977418 ]
 [0.         1.         0.53992755 0.24199218 0.06786818]
 [0.28003392 0.53992755 0.58108559 0.29561698 0.23971144]
 [0.24068132 0.24199218 0.29561698 0.21599542 0.18374313]
 [0.1977418  0.06786818 0.23971144 0.18374313 0.21586778]]
```

I get an output suggesting that it is not Unitary which means columns are not orthonormal. I can't seem to figure out what the mistake in here is.