# Generating invertible matrices in numpy/tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I would like to generate invertible matrices (specifically those from `GL(n)`, a general linear group of size n) using Tensorflow and/or Numpy for use with my neural network.

How can this be done and what would be the best way of doing so?

I understand there is a way to generate symmetric invertible matrices by computing `(A + A.T)/2` for arbitrary square matrices `A`, however, I would like mine to not just be symmetric.

Comment: One way that I can think of is to randomly assign **non**-zero integers to all the elements in the matrix, except for one element (let's say the element is X). Now calculate the determinant in terms of X let's call it equation A, now X can take any random value provided equation A is not zero.

Comment: A*(A transpose) is a guaranteed invertible matrix too. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190532/guaranteed-invertible-matrix

Comment: @AMISHGUPTA Thanks for the first one, I like that, but since the determinant is determined anyways, what issues would there be for assigning 0 to matrix entries as well? For the second one, it's assumed that the underlying matrix A has linearly independent rows which for the square matrices I wish to generate means I require invertible matrices A to generate other invertible `A@A.T` matrices.

Comment: you could generate  linearly independent random rows.  Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210354/generating-random-vector-thats-linearly-independent-of-a-set-of-vectors

Comment: @AMISHGUPTA That is one of doing it, but I believe it to be numerically unstable. It's effectively generating random vectors and testing to see if it's linearly independent of the other generated vectors. I believe with large dimensional vectors there's a chance of (uncertain) infinite runtime. I believe I found a more numerically stable approach updated as an answer to my post. Thanks for your inputs nonetheless!

Comment: I forgot to answer your first question before, assigning 0 would be a problem because you end up with terms like 0*X in the equation A, and we wouldn't want that. so one way out is to not assign 0s.

Comment: @AMISHGUPTA I see, so it further tackles one of the numerical instability issues this way - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I happened to have found one way which I believe can generate a large variety of random invertible matrices using diagonal dominance.

The theorem is that given an `nxn` matrix, if the `abs` of the diagonal element is larger than the sum of the `abs` of all the row elements with respect to the row the diagonal element is in, and this holds true for all rows, then the underlying matrix is invertible. (here is the corresponding wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix)

Therefore the following code snippet generates an arbitrary invertible matrix.

```
n = 5 # size of invertible matrix I wish to generate
m = np.random.rand(n, n)
mx = np.sum(np.abs(m), axis=1)
np.fill_diagonal(m, mx)
```

Comment: very nice; only observation is that it necessarily creates a matrix with diagonals >> offdiagonals. Extremely elegant implementation!