# Pytorch parallelize linalg.solve() loop

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, parallel-processing, linear-algebra

**Goal:**
I have a function calling `torch.linalg.solve()` that I want to run as fast as I can.

**Setup:** I have an `input_array` (size `50x100x100`). I have a `host_array` (size `100x100x100`?. My function `solver` inputs `input_array[:,i,j]` and outputs a vector size 100 to store in `host_array[:,i,j]`. I am running a nested loop through all rows and columns of `input_array` to populate `host_array`.

**Problem:** This is slow to run, especially considering my real case where each call of the function takes a second.
I am running it with a nested loop, and I would like to know if it would be faster by parallelizing my function ?

**Example Code:**

```
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm

# Create host_array and input_array with random data
host_array = torch.zeros(100, 500, 500)
input_array = torch.randn(50, 500, 500)

# Create a dummy coefficient matrix A (50x100)
A = torch.randn(50, 100)

# Define your function to solve for input_array[:, i, j] and update host_array[:, i, j]
def solver(input_vector, A):

    # Solve the linear system of equation
    solution = torch.linalg.solve(A.T@A, A.T@input_vector)

    return solution

# Calculate total runtime
total_iterations = int(host_array.shape[1]*host_array.shape[2])
progress_bar = tqdm(total=total_iterations, dynamic_ncols=False, mininterval=1.0)

# Iterate through the input_array
for i in range(host_array.shape[1]):
    for j in range(host_array.shape[2]):
        host_array[:,i,j] = solver(input_array[:,i,j], A)
        progress_bar.update(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the broadcasting capabilities of [`torch.linalg.solve()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.solve.html) to gain a significant speedup – see the section `# proposed solution` and, in particular, the function `solver_batch()` in my code below. I annotated the shapes that result from the necessary reshapings (squeezing, unsqueezing, and permuting) of the inputs.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import torch

torch.manual_seed(42)  # Make result reproducible

B, C = 500, 500
M, N = 100, 50

input_array = torch.randn(N, B, C)
A = torch.randn(N, M)

# Proposed solution

t_start = datetime.now()
def solver_batch(inpt, a):
    at_a = a.T @ a  # MxM
    inpt = inpt.permute(1, 2, 0).unsqueeze(-1)  # BxCxNx1
    at_input = a.T @ inpt  # BxCxMx1
    
    result = torch.linalg.solve(at_a, at_input)  # BxCxMx1
    return result.squeeze(-1).permute(2, 0, 1)  # MxBxC

proposed_result = solver_batch(input_array, A)
t_stop = datetime.now()
print(f"Proposed solution took {(t_stop - t_start).total_seconds():.2f}s")

# Previous solution

t_start = datetime.now()
host_array = torch.zeros(M, B, C)  # Will hold the result

def solver(input_vector, A):
    return torch.linalg.solve(A.T@A, A.T@input_vector)

for i in range(host_array.shape[1]):
    for j in range(host_array.shape[2]):
        host_array[:,i,j] = solver(input_array[:,i,j], A)
t_stop = datetime.now()
print(f"Previous solution took {(t_stop - t_start).total_seconds():.2f}s")

# Check results

left = (A.T @ A) @ host_array.permute(1, 2, 0).unsqueeze(-1)
right = A.T @ input_array.permute(1, 2, 0).unsqueeze(-1)
print("(A.T @ A) @ host_array      == A.T @ input_array?",
      torch.allclose(left, right, atol=1e-3))

left = (A.T @ A) @ proposed_result.permute(1, 2, 0).unsqueeze(-1)
right = A.T @ input_array.permute(1, 2, 0).unsqueeze(-1)
print("(A.T @ A) @ proposed_result == A.T @ input_array?",
      torch.allclose(left, right, atol=1e-3))
```

On my machine, I got:

```py
>>> Proposed solution took 0.62s
>>> Previous solution took 21.74s
>>> (A.T @ A) @ host_array      == A.T @ input_array? True
>>> (A.T @ A) @ proposed_result == A.T @ input_array? True
```

Note that, while both `host_array` and `proposed_result` hold *valid solutions*, they do not necessarily hold *the same solution* (in fact, for the given random seed, they are not the same). This, if I understand correctly, is because the result of `torch.linalg.solve()` is unique if and only if its first argument (`A.T @ A` in our case) is invertible, which it does not necessarily seem to be. If you want to check that both your and my approach indeed produce the same solution (subject to numerical error) for an invertible matrix, you could construct yourself an `MxM` invertible matrix following [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73426718/) and replace `A.T @ A` with it for testing purposes.

Also note that, when comparing the result with `torch.allclose()`, I had to be quite generous (`atol=1e-3`) as quite some numerical error seems to build up.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for you answer ! 
I will accept it because it perfectly solves the question I described, but I realized I kind of forgot an important point in my problem. 
The point-by-point read and write that I do is mandatory because the amount of rows of A (A.shape[0]) changes depending on the point input, but not its amount of columns. Hence the output of the solver always having the set size of A.shape[1].
But that's my bad so I will definitely accept your answer !

Comment: @vdc Oh, that indeed makes a difference! :) It might still be possible to go without a loop though: can you pad A to some maximum number of rows, filling up unused rows with zeros if necessary? But maybe I am missing the point. Do you think it makes sense to post a new question?

Comment: @vdc I just spotted a typo in the heading of your question: it should be "parallelize", not "paralellize"

Comment: Yeah maybe I should ask a new question because I think your example just shows nicely how to to it. I'm gonna write a new example this afternoon ! And correct the typo. Thanks for that !

Comment: New question has been posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77377232/parallelize-a-pytorch-function-running-on-gpu