# Parallelize a pytorch function running on GPU

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, gpu, linear-algebra

**Goal:** I have a function called by a loop that inputs a 1D tensor, and a 2D tensor. I use `torch.linalg.solve()` in this function. I want to parallelize the loop to optimize the runtime.

**Setup:** I have 3 main tensors:

1. `input_tensor`: size 50x100x100
2. `host_tensor`: size 100x100x100
3. `A`: size 50x100 (design matrix)

`input_tensor` has 100x100 `input_vector`, all length 50. They also all have a different amount of NaNs that I mask, hence the `input_vector` masked having a **length inferior or equal to 50**. Note that the design matrix `A` will also be masked and have size (mask x 100).

Because each `input_vector` and `A` have different masked lengths, the function needs to be run point-by-point.

**Problem:** Is there a way to make the following code faster ? How could I deal with the design matrix `A` and `input_vector` having different sizes at each iteration ?

**Important:** The NaNs can not be replaced by 0 as this would defeat the process of the linear solving process. As background, I asked a question about similar process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77370853/pytorch-parallelize-linalg-solve-loop).

**Code:**

```
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

# Create "device" so we can migrate the tensors to GPU
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Set the seed for reproducibility
torch.manual_seed(42) 

# Set shapes to generate tensors
B, C = 500, 500
M, N = 100, 50

# Generate tensors
input_tensor = torch.randn(N, B, C)
host_tensor = torch.randn(M, B, C)
A = torch.randn(N, M)

# --- Here we input random NaNs in the input_tensor to simulate missing data --- #
# Define the probability of inserting NaN at each element
probability = 0.2  # You can adjust this as needed

# Generate random indices based on the probability
shape = input_tensor.shape
random_indices = torch.rand(shape) < probability

# Replace the selected indices with NaN values
input_tensor[random_indices] = float('nan')

# --- Migrate matrices to GPU --- #
A = A.to(device)
input_tensor = input_tensor.to(device)
host_tensor = host_tensor.to(device)
A = A.to(device)

t_start = datetime.now()
# --- Function that creates a vector size M from input_vector (size N) and A
def solver(input_vector, A):

    # We create a mask to reduce the row size of A: rows where input_vector is NaN are not considered in the solver
    mask = ~torch.isnan(input_vector)

    # Mask the vector
    input_vector_masked = input_vector[mask]

    # Mask the array
    A_masked = A[mask]
    A_trans = A_masked.T

    # Solve the linear system of equation: A.TA = A.Tvec_Obs
    return torch.linalg.solve(A_trans@A_masked, A_trans@input_vector_masked)


# --- Iterate through each vector of the input_tensor --- #

# Define the total number of iterations
total_iterations = B*C
# Create a tqdm progress bar
progress_bar = tqdm(total=total_iterations, dynamic_ncols=False, mininterval=1.0)

# Iterate through every cell of input_array
for i in range(host_tensor.shape[1]):
    for j in range(host_tensor.shape[2]):
        host_tensor[:,i,j] = solver(input_tensor[:,i,j], A)
        progress_bar.update(1)  # Update the progress bar
t_stop = datetime.now()


print(f"Inversion took {(t_stop - t_start).total_seconds():.2f}s")
```

Comment: There probably isn't a good solution for what you're looking for. GPUs don't like multiprocessing on the same card and they don't like dealing with tensors of mixed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a bit of an unsatisfactory answer here. But let's go step by step.

### Zeroing `nan`s == dropping `nan`s

First of all, you *can* replace the `nan`s with zeros. Take the following example: Assume you have a vector `v` and a matrix `A`, given as

```py
v = [v1 v2 v3]  # N elements
A = [[a11 a12 a13]  # NxM elements
     [a21 a22 a23]
     [a31 a32 a33]]
```

Now, assume `v2 = nan` and thus needs to be suppressed.

What you are currently doing in `solver()` is getting the non-`nan` elements of `v` as `m`, the corresponding rows of `A` as `M` and then calculate `A_for_solving = M.T @ M` and `B_for_solving = M.T @ v`, namely

```py
m = [v1 v3]  # Masked v (n < N elements)
M = [[a11 a12 a13]  # Masked A (nxM elements)
     [a31 a32 a33]]
A_for_solving = M.T @ M  # MxM elements
B_for_solving = M.T @ m  # M elements
result = linalg.solve(A_for_solving, B_for_solving)
```

You should notice two things here:

1. The shapes of `A_for_solving` and `B_for_solving` always remain the same, no matter how many elements from `v` (and thus rows from `A`) are dropped: `A_for_solving` is always an M×M matrix and `B_for_solving` is always an M-element vector. This hints at the possibility that we can actually still parallelize our calculation.
2. What's more, if you would replace the `nan`s in `v` and the corresponding rows in `A` with zeros, you would yield exactly the same values in `A_for_solving` and `B_for_solving`!

   In other words, you could do the following:

   ```py
   z = [v1 0 v3]  # Zeroed v
   Z = [[a11 a12 a13]  # Zeroed A
        [  0   0   0]
        [a31 a32 a33]]
   A_for_solving = Z.T @ Z
   B_for_solving = Z.T @ z
   result = linalg.solve(A_for_solving, B_for_solving)
   ```

   … and you would get exactly the same inputs to `linalg.solve()` as before!

You can easily check this with your current code by extending it for testing purposes as follows:

```py
def solver(input_vector, A):

    mask = ~torch.isnan(input_vector)
    input_vector_masked = input_vector[mask]

    A_masked = A[mask]
    A_trans = A_masked.T
    
    # Start sanity check: nan-zeroing is the same as nan-dropping
    A_zeroed = A.clone(); A_zeroed[~mask] = 0
    input_vector_zeroed = input_vector.clone(); input_vector_zeroed[~mask] = 0
    assert torch.allclose(A_masked.T @ A_masked,
                          A_zeroed.T @ A_zeroed, atol=1e-5)
    assert torch.allclose(A_masked.T @ input_vector_masked,
                          A_zeroed.T @ input_vector_zeroed, atol=1e-5)
    # End sanity check
    
    return torch.linalg.solve(A_trans@A_masked, A_trans@input_vector_masked)
```

### Batched calculation

If we use the zeroing approach, we can parallelize our code again, as we now have inputs of the same size for each mask again. The corresponding function could look as follows:

```py
def solver_batch(inpt, a):
    inpt = inpt.permute(1, 2, 0).unsqueeze(-1)  # BxCxNx1
    mask = torch.isnan(inpt)  # CAUTION: True for NaNs, unlike `mask` in the question!
    a_zeroed = a.repeat(*inpt.shape[:2], 1, 1)  # BxCxNxM
    a_zeroed[mask.expand(-1, -1, -1, a.shape[-1])] = 0
    at_a = a_zeroed.transpose(-2, -1) @ a_zeroed  # BxCxMxM
    inpt_zeroed = inpt.clone()
    inpt_zeroed[mask] = 0
    at_input = a_zeroed.transpose(-2, -1) @ inpt_zeroed  # BxCxMx1
    result = torch.linalg.solve(at_a, at_input)
    return result.squeeze(-1).permute(2, 0, 1)  # MxBxC
```

### Caveats

The batched solution is quite similar to the [answer that I posted to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77375561/7395592). There are two caveats though:

#### Caveat 1: Memory usage

As we need a different matrix `A` and thus `A.T @ A` for each input vector now, we end up with a tensor `at_a` of size 500×500×100×100 in your given example. This is *huge* (a tensor of 2.5 billion elements in this case). In my case, it doesn't fit on the GPU, so what I had to do is process the input tensor in chunks:

```py
chunk_size = 50  # TODO: adjust chunk size for your hardware
for lo in range(0, input_tensor.shape[-1], chunk_size):
    chunk_result = solver_batch(input_tensor[..., lo:lo+chunk_size], A)
    host_tensor[..., lo:lo+chunk_size] = chunk_result
```

This is still much faster than processing the input element-wise though.

#### Caveat 2: Numerical instability

I tried to sanity-check results with the following for-loop, similar to the sanity check in my previous answer:

```py
for i in range(host_tensor.shape[1]):
    for j in range(host_tensor.shape[2]):
        input_vec = input_tensor[..., i, j]
        res_vec = host_tensor[..., i, j]
        mask = ~torch.isnan(input_vec)
        M = A[mask]
        assert torch.allclose((M.T @ M) @ res_vec, M.T @ input_vec[mask], atol=1e-3)
```

What we check here is that `A @ X = B` should hold for `X = solve(A, B)` by definition. This, however, seems not to be the case with the given data, *neither for mine nor for your approach*. I don't know if this is a problem of numerical instabilities (my maths skills are lacking there) or whether I made some stupid mistake.

Comment: That is really neat !!! I feared doing the large matrix approach because I didn't know how to deal with the memory issues, but it seems that you approach would work just well if I adapt it to my dataset ! I'm gonna try it and see if I get a better feel of the reason behind the numerical errors.

Comment: Good luck! Let me know if it works out.